# I need some tikz examples

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I never used the `tikz` package before. Now I need the commands for drawing the following figures:
[image]

Comment: [Here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/) is a large database of examples.

Comment: The manual (e.g. https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0) has a series of tutorials in chapters 2-6.

Comment: [latexdraw](https://latexdraw.com/) has many easy to follow tutorials

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% for specifications like "left=of ..."
\usetikzlibrary{automata}% automata related stuff
\usetikzlibrary{calc}% for calculating coordinates, like ($...$)
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% arrow head Stealth[round]

% define settings common to several automata
\tikzset{FAstyle/.style={
    shorten >=1pt,% leave a thin space between arrow head and target node
    node distance=3cm,% grid size
    on grid,% arrange nodes on a grid
    auto,% automatic placements of labels
    every state/.style={% define appearance of nodes
      draw=blue!50,
      very thick,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=blue!20,
      minimum size=0pt
    },
    >=Stealth[round],
    thick,
    draw=black!50
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[FAstyle]
  \node[state,initial,initial text=] (S) {S};
  \node[state,right=of S] (A) {A};
  \node[state,below=of S] (B) {B};
  \node[state,accepting,right=of B] (C) {C};
  \path[->] (S) edge[bend right=20] node{a} (A)
                edge[bend right=20] node[swap]{$\lambda$} (B)
            (A) edge[bend right=20] node[swap]{a,b} (S)
                edge node[swap]{b} (B)
                edge node{$\lambda$} (C)
            (B) edge[bend right=20] node[swap]{a} (S)
                edge[bend left=20] node{b,$\lambda$} (C)
            (C) edge[bend left=20] node{a,b} (B)
  ;
  \draw ($(B)+(-1,-1)$) rectangle ($(C)+(1,1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `arrows` library is considered deprecated by the way, and is superseded by `arrows.meta`. The old `arrows` is still available for backwards compatibility, as I understand it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I have replace the arrow head.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following examples:

- [A Petri-net for Hagen](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/nodetutorial/)
- [State machine](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/)